# Convexity of probability densities of bounded variation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convex-analysis

Let $0 \leq a < b < \infty$ be fixed constants, and $K := [0, 1]$.

Then let $\mathcal{H}_{a}^{b} := \left\{h \colon K \to [a, b] \mid \int_{K} h d \mu = 1, h \text{ measurable} \right\}$, be the set of uniformly bounded probability densities on $K$.

**Addendum:** Further let us endow $\mathcal{H}_{a}^{b}$ with the $L_{2}$-metric, i.e., for all $f_1, f_2 \in \mathcal{H}_{a}^{b}$
$$\|f_1 - f_2\|_{2} := \left(\int_{G} (f_1 - f_2)^{2} d\mu \right)^{1 / 2}.$$ In what follows all arguments about compactness, closedness will be made with respect to the topology induced by the $L_2$ metric on $\mathcal{H}_{a}^{b}$.

Now consider the following sets of densities:

1. Densities of **bounded variation**:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{BV}_{a}^{b} := \left\{f \colon K \to [a, b] \mid \left\| f \right\|_{\infty} \leq b, V(f, m) \leq b, m \in \mathbb{N}, \int_{K} f d \mu = 1, f \text{ measurable} \right\},
\end{equation}
where $V(f, m) := \sup_{0 \leq x_{1} < x_{2} < \cdots < x_{m} \leq 1} \sum_{i=1}^m\left|f\left(x_{i+1}\right)-f\left(x_i\right)\right|$, given $m \in \mathbf{N}$.

I have the following questions about $\mathbf{BV}_{a}^{b}$:

1. Is $\mathbf{BV}_{a}^{b}$ proper subsets of $\mathcal{H}_{a}^{b}$
2. If so, is $\mathbf{BV}_{a}^{b}$ a **compact** subset of $\mathcal{H}_{a}^{b}$?
3. Is $\mathbf{BV}_{a}^{b}$ a **totally bounded** subset of  $\mathcal{H}_{a}^{b}$?
4. Is $\mathbf{BV}_{a}^{b}$ a convex set?
5. If not for above questions, what are basic sufficient conditions that would be required to ensure that $\mathbf{BV}_{a}^{b}$ is either a compact, totally bounded, or convex subset of $\mathcal{H}_{a}^{b}$.

Any justification for these questions would better help me get an understanding of these commonly used probability density classes in statistics.

Note that these definitions are taken from Section 6.4 in Yang, Yuhong, and Andrew Barron. "Information-theoretic determination of minimax rates of convergence." Annals of Statistics (1999): 1564-1599. See [here for the paper](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Earb4/publications_files/Information-TheoreticDeterminationOfMinimaxRatesOfConvergenceAnnalsStatistics.pdf).

**Note:** If I've misinterpreted the paper and definitions above, please let me know so that I can amend the question correctly.

Comment: You need to specify a metric/topology on $H^b_a$ to be able to speak about compactness.

Comment: @daw sorry, you are right. I've amended to clarify that we are only concerned with the $L_2$ topology on $\mathcal{H}_{a}^{b}$, and $\mathbf{BV}_{a}^{b}$.